# How to get the HTTP request header and body as an string in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, http

I have a HttpPost object (org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost) that is being constructed in java code.

Now I'd like to read the HTTP request content that it created (header and body).

Is it possible to generate an string with that info?
Or some other way to read that content.

It's an API, not a web app and I'm using Eclipse.

thanks.

Comment: Please share your code what have you done so far.

Comment: httppost.getAllHeaders() and httppost.getEntity(). getContent() - use bufferedreader to read the content

Comment: @Abhinav Pandey this sounds like a good idea. Do you have a code sample?